# 分散が等しい時、1標本t検定と2標本t検定の違いについて

Tags: r

例えば、以下データのように、分散は等しく、平均値が違う場合です。
1標本t検定(0.002111)と2標本t検定(0.001053)の検定結果から、単純に1標本t検定の結果の方が、2倍高いと考えてよいのでしょうか。
どなたかアドバイスをお願いしてもよろしいでしょうか。

```
x1<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
x2<-c(6,7,8,9,10)
(m1<-mean(x1)) # 3
(m2<-mean(x2)) # 8
(var1<-var(x1)) # 2.5
(var2<-var(x2)) # 2.5

t.test(x1,mu=8,alternative="two.sided")
#        One Sample t-test
#data:  x1
#t = -7.0711, df = 4, p-value = 0.002111

t.test(x1,x2,alternative="two.sided") 
#        Welch Two Sample t-test
#data:  x1 and x2
#t = -5, df = 8, p-value = 0.001053
```

Comment: 1標本検定の p値 (0.002) が 2標本t検定のp値 (0.001) の大きさと比べて2倍というのはそのとおりだと思いますが, 両者を比べる意図がわかりません.

Comment: コメントをありがとうございます。おっしゃる通り変な質問でした。比べるには、自由度もおかしい。検定する時点で1標本か2標本か決まっているはずなので、そもそも比べる必要はないのですが、数あるケースで、2つの群の分散が全く同じだった場合、どうなのかなと思い、変な質問をしてしまいました。